# OpenFire and OAuth2 connectivity

Tags: openfire

I experimented with getting OpenFire connecting to an LDAP system, but has anyone tried to use OAuth2?

I am looking for some form of connection plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found a plugin example of this at https://github.com/rxwen/openfire-oauth-auth-provider

I modified it for my purposes and it solved the issue I needed solved.